# mysql prepared statements, trouble understanding how it works

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

i am trying to use prepared statements but having trouble getting it to successfully run.
here is my code:

```
 function addAlbum($album){
        $connection = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DATABASE);
        /*$sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_ALBUMS.'` (albumName) VALUES ("'.$album.'")';
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);*/
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_ALBUMS.'` (albumName) VALUES ("'.$album.'")');
        $stmt->bindParam(':albumName', $album);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if($result){
            header("Location: index.php?success");
        } else {
            header("Location: index.php?fail");
        }

    }
```

i have ran this in firefox with errors on and this is what i get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   mysqli_stmt::bindParam() in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHPproject/includes/functions.inc.php
>   on line 16

could any one please tell me where i am going wrong?

many thanks

Comment: Should we assume that your script outputs `Nooooo`?

Comment: Are you using google-chrome? Google Chrome does not show up all the errors correctly, so please use firefox for this.
Also you should enable error output in php

Comment: thanks, ok i have updated the post to show the fatal error i get when i run my function.

Comment: I edited my answer. Check out the right function name.

Comment: the php.net website bindParam, when it was bind_param. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First argument for bind should be the type of variable:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $album);
```

Also you should check the return value of `execute()` and not the `$stmt`:

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
if($result){
  echo "yes";
}
else {
  echo "no";
}
```

Also I'd say that it's not a good ideea to prepare the statement each time you insert something. Prepared statements should be class variables or if you're not in oop, global variables, so you don't prepare the statement each time you call the function. Just write a function `init()` that will prepare all the statements that you'll use.

Comment: thanks for your advice, i still cant seem to get it to run, i have checked to see PDO is installed in my php.ini file and it is not commented out.

Comment: i have edited my post to show the latest function and the browser error i get.